# python, calling a method from another class

Tags: python, class, object, oop, methods

I am trying to call the `sum_method` function from my evaluation class to my main one, however I run into many errors. I want to use the `new_data` as the data parameter of my `sum_method` function.

evaluation class:

```
class evaluation():

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def sum_method(self):
        montant_init = self.data.loc[self.data['Initiateur'] == 'Glovoapp', 'Montant (centimes)'].sum()
        print(montant_init)
```

main class:

```
class main(evaluation):

        new_data.to_csv("transactions.csv", index=False)

        self.data = new_data

    def call_sum(self, new_data):
       
        init_eval = evaluation.sum_method(self=new_data)
        print(init_eval)


init_evalobj = main()
init_evalobj.call_sum()
```

Comment: _What_ errors? Give a [mre].

Comment: oh yes sorry for not giving more detail, it would either be attribute errors or 1 required positional argument:

Comment: Please [edit] the question accordingly, and cut your code down to the relevant parts.

Comment: " I want to use the new_data as the data parameter of my sum_method function." ... that is not what you are doing. sum_method() does not take a data parameter, it uses the value already set in the self.data member variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use the method in your inherence class just use `self`

so:

```
init_eval = self.sum_method()
```

the self argument is passed in python automaticly as first parameter

*update*
you also should return a value:

```
    def sum_method(self):
        montant_init = self.data.loc[self.data['Initiateur'] == 'Glovoapp', 'Montant (centimes)'].sum()
        print(montant_init)
        return montant_init
```

Comment: thank you for you answer! I am trying it (no errors) however I can't see an output

Comment: can you please mark the question as answered, thank you sir

Comment: Yes, of course I will once I manage to make it work. For now, when I am running the code, it doesn't give me any output.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making some changes to the both classes, to encapsulate the .data member variable in the base class. My preference would also be to separate out the calculation from the display, so leave all the print statements in the call_sum() function.

```
class evaluation:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def sum_method(self):
        montant_init = self.data.loc[self.data['Initiateur'] == 'Glovoapp', 'Montant (centimes)'].sum()
        return montant_init


class main(evaluation):

    def __init__(self):
        # Reduce csv content to what's needed for analysis
        data_csv = pd.read_csv('transactions.csv')

        # --> removing unnecessary data
        new_data = data_csv[['Opération', 'Initiateur', 'Montant (centimes)', 'Monnaie',
                             'Date', 'Résultat', 'Compte marchand', 'Adresse IP Acheteur', 'Marque de carte']]

        # --> saving changes...
        new_data.to_csv("transactions.csv", index=False)

        super().__init__(new_data) //Initialize the base class

    def call_sum(self):
        print('Glovoapp "montant" generated')
        init_eval = self.sum_method() //Call the method from the base class
        print(init_eval)
```